# CodeIgniter replaces "+" with whitespace

Tags: php, codeigniter, json-deserialization

We have a login api in which a user's login email is `ttramos+@example.com.ph`.

The login api works on iOS and the Web version but fails on Android and Postman. We tried returning the value that was being fed into the method but it returns it as `ttramos @globe.com.ph`. It replaced the `+` with a whitespace. Any idea what's causing this?

```
public function signin_post()
{
   if ($params = json_decode($this->post(‘params’), true)) {

       $creds = [
           ‘email’    => $params[‘email’],
           ‘password’ => $params[‘password’]
       ];

       $user = $this->UsersModel->login($creds);

       $return = [‘response’ => ‘SUCCESS’, ‘details’ => $user];

       } else {
           if ($user == ‘WRONG_PASSWORD’) {
               $return = [‘response’ => ‘INVALID_PASSWORD’, ‘details’ => null];
           } else {
               $return = [‘response’ => ‘INVALID_EMAIL’, ‘details’ => null];
           }
       }

      $this->response($return, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
   }

   $this->response(NULL, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
```

}

Comment: Your code is invalud, there’s a missing `if`. But from what you’ve written there, there is no reason why that would be happening. Can you show us an example of the data you’re sending using Postman?

Comment: Also show us how you send/ submit this data. Sounds like a problem with URL encoding/ decoding at some level.

Comment: usually its because of URL encoding/decoding as said above by @misorude.